# regular expression to match urls of specific site

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a python regular expression that will match both these URLs:

```
http://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/WM6N3G_Battle_Mountain_State_Park
http://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/WM6N3G
```

and for both will capture:

```
http://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/WM6N3G
```

This is what I have:

```
(http://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/.*?)_?.*?
```

But it only matches:

```
http://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(http://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/[^_]*).*
```

Comment: Better than my answer.  The [^_] is great.

Comment: Damn was too slow :(. Possibly should use + given that there should always be one or more.

Comment: Note that a negated character class will also match newlines. Of course, it depends on the format of the source strings whether this could be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
(http://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/[^_]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

non regex way

```
url="http://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/WM6N3G_Battle_Mountain_State_Park"
s = url.split("_")
print s[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

*? makes something completely optional and won't be included if it doesn't have to

```
(http://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/[^_]+)(_.*)?)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
 (http://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/[a-zA-Z0-9]*)_?.*?
```

Answer (score 0):

`.*(http://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/WM6N3G).*` if it is inline

.*? is non-greedy, and so will give up everything except for one character, in this case.